# Retopology after sculpting

Tags: retopology

Been sculpting for a while and watched vids on retopolgy but absolutely none explain what to do after it.

None explain what to do after retop is done in preparing it for animation or exporting it to engines like unity/unreal.

“Just slap a multi res modifier and boom it’s done, good luck after that though” Mhmm yep, now what about a step after that?

1: Do I need to apply the shrink wrap mod after retop?

2: Do I need to apply the sub div/ multires after that if I want to animate/texture/rig my character? If I do I’m back to square one with a high poly count model.

Is there no other way ?

Is this workflow what sculptors use here on blender?

Sculpt > retop > keep modifiers on > add textures / rig > bake

This is kinda making me tear my hair.

Suggestions needed and welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about how you use the Multires, I guess it's on the high-poly tht is sculpted? When you retopo you have 2 objects: the original high-poly, the retopo low-poly. Once you have finished the retopo, apply the Shrinkwrap of the low-poly if you've used one, don't apply the Subdivision Surface if you're using one, and it should be good, rig this low-poly and so on. Also keep the high-poly in case of

Comment: Also if you want to keep the details of the high-poly you'll need to bake the normals, there are plenty of tutorials on this topic

Comment: You use retopology for two reasons: To optimize the sculpted figure topology and keep adding fine details with Multiresolution modifier on. Or prepare a low-poly version for games and animation. In both cases after retopology you apply all helping modifiers. Before moving forward usually you create a UV Map for the model, which makes life easier when transferring details from high-poly to low poly versions of the model.

Comment: for  more context that I accidentally left out, I'm using that quad remesher add on for blender to speed up my retopology workflow

Comment: It depends what you're trying to remesh,if it's a piece of the setup, a remesher is ok, if it's for an object that you want to animate, it won't give a clean result and you need to retopologize manually